# AWS userdata does not run on custom Ubuntu AMI

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws, user-data, autoinstall

I've created a custom Ubuntu ISO with Autoinstall and userdata to set up a virtual machine (VM) in our VMware setup. This VM is then converted to OVA format, uploaded to AWS S3, and converted to an Amazon Machine Image (AMI). We use this AMI to create EC2 instances, where we run some initial setup commands to prepare for AMI generation.

We aim to make a reliable AMI that can run userdata scripts. However, we're facing a major problem: EC2 instances created from this AMI are not processing userdata. I think this might be related to how userdata is executed in the original VM. Can anyone help figure out why **userdata isn't working in these EC2 instances** and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the *cloud-init* `Ec2` datasource then the autoinstall file that is used to create the VM should contain something like this

```
#cloud-config
autoinstall:
  late-commands:
    - |
      rm /target/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml
      rm /target/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg
      rm /target/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/curtin-preserve-sources.cfg
      rm /target/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg
      true
```

The general idea is to convert the "installed-image" to a "cloud-image" by deleting the files created by the installer, *subiquity*, that configure *cloud-init*.

Files created by *subiquity* include

- `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` to provide a prepared network configuration.  If the image is moved to AWS then this network configuration may be unwanted.
- `/target/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/subiquity-disable-cloudinit-networking.cfg` to prevent *cloud-init* from configuring the network again.  If you move the image to AWS then you may need to configure the network.
- `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/curtin-preserve-sources.cfg` to prevent *cloud-init* from configuring apt again.  If you move the image to AWS then you may need to configure apt.
- `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg` to contain installer configuration based on selected install options.  This includes first-boot configuration like creating the first user and configuring OpenSSH.  This installer configuration is added as the `None` datasource.

The file `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg` also includes the configuration

```
datasource_list:
- None
```

I believe this is causing *cloud-init* to skip over your AWS userdata since it does not look for the `Ec2` datasource.  The default list of datasources is configured in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/90_dpkg.cfg`, but gets overridden by `99-installer.cfg`.

**Pitfalls**

- The first-boot configuration in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-installer.cfg` will **not** be run.  This configuration would have to be recreated in the `Ec2` datasource.  If the image needs to work in VMware and AWS then additional configuration would be required so *cloud-init* behaves as desired in both environments.
- If you boot your installed-image VM before converting to an AMI then *cloud-init* behavior changes even more.

**Notes**

- My experience is from testing using Ubuntu 22.04 (`subiquity 22.04.2`).
- You can download from https://cloud-images.ubuntu.com/ to compare the "cloud-image" to the created installed-image.

Comment: Thank you. I fixed it with something like you mentioned above. Now, I don't manage to run AWS userdata (when launching an instance from my AMI), unless I use: `#cloud-boothook`, but then it runs every boot, which it's not my desired.